# php associative array_search odd behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, search, associative

So this is getting on my nerves right now
I have an associative array that I populate from another array:

```
foreach ($possible_unavailable as $p) {
    $aux[] = array('date' => $p['date'], 'status' => -1);
}
var_dump($aux);
```

And then I do the following:

```
foreach ($aux as $pu) {
   var_dump($pu['date']);
   var_dump(array_search($pu['date'], $aux));
}
```

This is the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2014-09-01"
    ["status"]=>
    int(-1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2014-09-05"
    ["status"]=>
    int(-1)
  }
}
string(10) "2014-09-01"
bool(false)
string(10) "2014-09-05"
bool(false)
```

Why "array_search($pu['date'], $aux)" is not returning true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search\_array in nested arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290713/search-array-in-nested-arrays)

Comment: my array is not multi dimensional, its just an associative array that has string values.

Comment: @dan yes it is, it's an array of arrays

Comment: You have _one_ nested array of _several_ associative arrays.

Comment: Yes but what I meant is that I dont have something like this: array("date" => array("2014-09-01", "2014-09-02") , "status" => -1), as the possible duplicate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, you are trying to search a string in an array filled with arrays, so the array_search is comparing an string with an array like this:

*is "2014-09-01" equals to array("date" => "2014-09-01", "status" => -1) ??*

Obviously the return value is false.

Comment: Thank you... I misunderstood the array_search function and got a little bit confused.
This solved it: array_search($pu['date'], $pu)