# Return individual keys with array_search inside find function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

When I run the following code I get the output "agriculture" but I want to return all entries for individual array keys from the entry that came up in the search for the data-code. For example:
Tasks, Tools_used, Knowledge.

As well as the first entry which in this case is "Picking and Packing".

How can I do this? Thank you.

I found the original code in this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291136/12822663

```
<?php

$indus['agriculture'] = [
    "Picking and Packing" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Examine and inspect containers, materials, or products to ensure that product quality and packing specifications are met.", "Measure, weigh, and count products and materials", "Record product, packaging, and order information on specified forms and records.", "Seal containers or materials, using glues, fasteners, nails, and hand tools.", "Assemble, line, and pad cartons, crates, and containers, using hand tools.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Box sealing tape dispensers", "Form or fill or seal machinery", "Staple guns", "Strapping dispenser", "Wrapping machinery",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Production and Processing", "Customer and Personal Service",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Near Vision", "Problem Sensitivity ", "Trunk Strength", "Manual Dexterity", "Multilimb Coordination",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Farm Worker" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Operate tractors, tractor-drawn machinery, and self-propelled machinery to plow, harrow and fertilize soil, or to plant, cultivate, spray and harvest crops.", "Operate tractors, tractor-drawn machinery, and self-propelled machinery to plow, harrow and fertilize soil, or to plant, cultivate, spray and harvest crops.", "Set up and operate irrigation equipment.","Repair and maintain farm vehicles, implements, and mechanical equipment.","Harvest fruits and vegetables by hand."
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Broadcast spreaders", "Greenhouse ventilation equipment", "Saws","Secateurs or pruning shears","Utility knives",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Multilimb Coordination", "Static Strength","Manual Dexterity","Trunk Strength","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "45-2092.00",
        ]
    ],
    "Agricultural Equipment Operator" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Load and unload crops or containers of materials, manually or using conveyors, handtrucks, forklifts, or transfer augers.", "Mix specified materials or chemicals, and dump solutions, powders, or seeds into planter or sprayer machinery.","Spray fertilizer or pesticide solutions to control insects, fungus and weed growth, and diseases, using hand sprayers.","Observe and listen to machinery operation to detect equipment malfunctions.","Manipulate controls to set, activate, and adjust mechanisms on machinery.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Container trailers", "Fertilizer spreaders or distributors","Harvesters","Haymaking machinery","Sprayers",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Operation and Control", "Operation Monitoring","Troubleshooting","Active Listening","Equipment Maintenance"
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Control Precision", "Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Depth Perception","Far Vision",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "45-2091.00",
        ]    
    ],
];

$indus['construction'] = [
    "Construction Labourer" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Tend pumps, compressors, or generators to provide power for tools, machinery, or equipment or to heat or move materials, such as asphalt", "Lubricate, clean, or repair machinery, equipment, or tools.", "Signal equipment operators to facilitate alignment, movement, or adjustment of machinery, equipment, or materials.", "Read plans, instructions, or specifications to determine work activities.", "Measure, mark, or record openings or distances to layout areas where construction work will be performed.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Levels", "Manlift or personnel lift", "Power saws", "Vacuum cleaners", "Water trucks",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction", "Public Safety and Security","Mechanical",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Speaking", "Active Listening","Coordination","Operation and Control","Operation Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "47-2061.00",
        ]
    ],
    "Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Learn and follow safety regulations.", "Take actions to avoid potential hazards or obstructions, such as utility lines, other equipment, other workers, or falling objects.", "Start engines, move throttles, switches, or levers, or depress pedals to operate machines, such as bulldozers, trench excavators, road graders, or backhoes.","Coordinate machine actions with other activities, positioning or moving loads in response to hand or audio signals from crew members.","Align machines, cutterheads, or depth gauge makers with reference stakes and guidelines or ground or position equipment, following hand signals of other workers.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Dump trucks", "Hydraulic truck cranes", "Power saws","Scrubbing machines","Water trucks",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Mechanical", "Public Safety and Security",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Operation and Control", "Equipment Maintenance","Operation Monitoring","Monitoring","Active Listening",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Control Precision", "Depth Perception","Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Far Vision",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "47-2073.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Check the forms that hold the concrete to see that they are properly constructed.", "Set the forms that hold concrete to the desired pitch and depth, and align them.","Spread, level, and smooth concrete, using rake, shovel, hand or power trowel, hand or power screed, and float.","Monitor how the wind, heat, or cold affect the curing of the concrete throughout the entire process.","Mold expansion joints and edges, using edging tools, jointers, and straightedge",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Batching plants or feeders", "Concrete spreaders","Floats","Power saws","Trowels",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction ", "Mathematics","Public Safety and Security",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Monitoring", "Coordination","Quality Control Analysis","Speaking","Time Management",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Manual Dexterity", "Trunk Strength","Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "47-2051.00"
        ]    
    ],
    "Brickmasons and Blockmasons" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Measure distance from reference points and mark guidelines to lay out work, using plumb bobs and levels.", "Construct corners by fastening in plumb position a corner pole or building a corner pyramid of bricks, and filling in between the corners using a line from corner to corner to guide each course, or layer, of brick.", "Apply and smooth mortar or other mixture over work surface.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Cold chisels", "Hammers", "Levels",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction", "Mathematics","Public Safety and Security","Design",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Coordination", "Critical Thinking","Active Listening","Monitoring","Operation Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Trunk Strength", "Extent Flexibility","Arm-Hand Steadiness","Manual Dexterity ","Near Vision",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "47-2021.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Fence Erector" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Establish the location for a fence, and gather information needed to ensure that there are no electric cables or water lines in the area.", "Set metal or wooden posts in upright positions in postholes.", "Measure and lay out fence lines and mark posthole positions, following instructions, drawings, or specifications.","Align posts, using lines or by sighting, and verify vertical alignment of posts, using plumb bobs or spirit levels.","Attach rails or tension wire along bottoms of posts to form fencing frames.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Pipe or tube cutter", "Pullers", "Staple guns","Tape measures","Wire cutters",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Customer and Personal Service", "Building and Construction","Transportation","Administration and Management","Design",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Active Listening", "Coordination","Critical Thinking","Monitoring","Speaking",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Manual Dexterity", "Trunk Strength","Multilimb Coordination","Static Strength","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "47-4031.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Surveying Technician" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "data-code" => [
          "17-3031.01"
        ]
    ],
    
];



$profcode ='53-7064.00';

function find($profcode, $indus) {
    foreach($indus as $key=>$value){
       if(is_array($value) && array_search($data-code, $profcode) !== false) {
          return $key;
       }
    }
    return false;
}

$cat = find($profcode, $indus);

echo $cat;
```

Comment: What is `$data-code`? A PHP variable cannot contains a minus sign (`-`). [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/array_search) need an array as second argument (here, `$profcode` is a string).

Comment: thank you. I am changing it to datacode.

Answer (score 1):

- The linked answer search into a 2 dimensions array. You have a 3 levels of depth in your array.
- `$data-code` is not a valid PHP variable (cannot contain a dash `-`).
- You can loop over the `$indus` values to search the wanted value using [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array).

Code

```
$profcode ='53-7064.00';

function find($profcode, $indus) {
    foreach($indus as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($profcode, $value['data-code'])) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

foreach($indus as $key => $values) {
    $cat = find($profcode, $values);
    if ($cat) {
        echo "Found in : $key -> $cat";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Found in : agriculture -> Picking and Packing
```

Working demo : https://3v4l.org/VdcOn