# Retrieve values from deep array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a 3 deep array. Currently, the code will isolate a record based on one field ($profcode) and show the heading. Eventually, I am going to build a table showing the information from all the other fields. The code so far is using in_array and a function that accepts $profcode.
I am unsure if (and how) I need to use array_keys() to do the next part when I retrieve the "Skills" field.
I tried:

```
foreach ($values as $value => $jobData1) {
   echo implode($jobData1['Skills']);
}
```

but it outputs:

> Entry1MonitoringEntry1Entry2Operation and ControlOperation
> MonitoringTroubleshootingActive ListeningEquipment Maintenance

It should be more like:

> Entry1Monitoring.

Yes, I will fix up the formatting once I know it's working.

I also tried:

```
if ( $jobData1['datacode'] = $profcode )
    {
    echo implode($jobData1['Skills']);
    }
```

Previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188570/return-individual-keys-with-array-search-inside-find-function-in-php)

Thank you.

I have included the full code on  ([replit](https://replit.com/@j354374/arraytest)) and here:

```php
$indus['agriculture'] = [
    "Picking and Packing" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Examine and inspect containers, materials, or products to ensure that product quality and packing specifications are met.", "Measure, weigh, and count products and materials", "Record product, packaging, and order information on specified forms and records.", "Seal containers or materials, using glues, fasteners, nails, and hand tools.", "Assemble, line, and pad cartons, crates, and containers, using hand tools.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Box sealing tape dispensers", "Form or fill or seal machinery", "Staple guns", "Strapping dispenser", "Wrapping machinery",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Production and Processing", "Customer and Personal Service",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Near Vision", "Problem Sensitivity ", "Trunk Strength", "Manual Dexterity", "Multilimb Coordination",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "53-7064.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Farm Worker" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Operate tractors, tractor-drawn machinery, and self-propelled machinery to plow, harrow and fertilize soil, or to plant, cultivate, spray and harvest crops.", "Operate tractors, tractor-drawn machinery, and self-propelled machinery to plow, harrow and fertilize soil, or to plant, cultivate, spray and harvest crops.", "Set up and operate irrigation equipment.","Repair and maintain farm vehicles, implements, and mechanical equipment.","Harvest fruits and vegetables by hand."
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Broadcast spreaders", "Greenhouse ventilation equipment", "Saws","Secateurs or pruning shears","Utility knives",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Multilimb Coordination", "Static Strength","Manual Dexterity","Trunk Strength","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "45-2092.00",
        ]
    ],
    "Agricultural Equipment Operator" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Load and unload crops or containers of materials, manually or using conveyors, handtrucks, forklifts, or transfer augers.", "Mix specified materials or chemicals, and dump solutions, powders, or seeds into planter or sprayer machinery.","Spray fertilizer or pesticide solutions to control insects, fungus and weed growth, and diseases, using hand sprayers.","Observe and listen to machinery operation to detect equipment malfunctions.","Manipulate controls to set, activate, and adjust mechanisms on machinery.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Container trailers", "Fertilizer spreaders or distributors","Harvesters","Haymaking machinery","Sprayers",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Operation and Control", "Operation Monitoring","Troubleshooting","Active Listening","Equipment Maintenance"
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Control Precision", "Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Depth Perception","Far Vision",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "45-2091.00",
        ]    
    ],
];

$indus['construction'] = [
    "Construction Labourer" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Tend pumps, compressors, or generators to provide power for tools, machinery, or equipment or to heat or move materials, such as asphalt", "Lubricate, clean, or repair machinery, equipment, or tools.", "Signal equipment operators to facilitate alignment, movement, or adjustment of machinery, equipment, or materials.", "Read plans, instructions, or specifications to determine work activities.", "Measure, mark, or record openings or distances to layout areas where construction work will be performed.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Levels", "Manlift or personnel lift", "Power saws", "Vacuum cleaners", "Water trucks",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction", "Public Safety and Security","Mechanical",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Speaking", "Active Listening","Coordination","Operation and Control","Operation Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3", "Entry4", "Entry5",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "47-2061.00",
        ]
    ],
    "Operating Engineers and Other Construction Equipment Operators" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Learn and follow safety regulations.", "Take actions to avoid potential hazards or obstructions, such as utility lines, other equipment, other workers, or falling objects.", "Start engines, move throttles, switches, or levers, or depress pedals to operate machines, such as bulldozers, trench excavators, road graders, or backhoes.","Coordinate machine actions with other activities, positioning or moving loads in response to hand or audio signals from crew members.","Align machines, cutterheads, or depth gauge makers with reference stakes and guidelines or ground or position equipment, following hand signals of other workers.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Dump trucks", "Hydraulic truck cranes", "Power saws","Scrubbing machines","Water trucks",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Mechanical", "Public Safety and Security",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Operation and Control", "Equipment Maintenance","Operation Monitoring","Monitoring","Active Listening",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Control Precision", "Depth Perception","Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Far Vision",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "47-2073.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Cement Masons and Concrete Finishers" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Check the forms that hold the concrete to see that they are properly constructed.", "Set the forms that hold concrete to the desired pitch and depth, and align them.","Spread, level, and smooth concrete, using rake, shovel, hand or power trowel, hand or power screed, and float.","Monitor how the wind, heat, or cold affect the curing of the concrete throughout the entire process.","Mold expansion joints and edges, using edging tools, jointers, and straightedge",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Batching plants or feeders", "Concrete spreaders","Floats","Power saws","Trowels",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction ", "Mathematics","Public Safety and Security",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Monitoring", "Coordination","Quality Control Analysis","Speaking","Time Management",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Manual Dexterity", "Trunk Strength","Multilimb Coordination","Near Vision","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "47-2051.00"
        ]    
    ],
    "Brickmasons and Blockmasons" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Measure distance from reference points and mark guidelines to lay out work, using plumb bobs and levels.", "Construct corners by fastening in plumb position a corner pole or building a corner pyramid of bricks, and filling in between the corners using a line from corner to corner to guide each course, or layer, of brick.", "Apply and smooth mortar or other mixture over work surface.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Cold chisels", "Hammers", "Levels",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Building and Construction", "Mathematics","Public Safety and Security","Design",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Coordination", "Critical Thinking","Active Listening","Monitoring","Operation Monitoring",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Trunk Strength", "Extent Flexibility","Arm-Hand Steadiness","Manual Dexterity ","Near Vision",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "47-2021.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Fence Erector" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Establish the location for a fence, and gather information needed to ensure that there are no electric cables or water lines in the area.", "Set metal or wooden posts in upright positions in postholes.", "Measure and lay out fence lines and mark posthole positions, following instructions, drawings, or specifications.","Align posts, using lines or by sighting, and verify vertical alignment of posts, using plumb bobs or spirit levels.","Attach rails or tension wire along bottoms of posts to form fencing frames.",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Pipe or tube cutter", "Pullers", "Staple guns","Tape measures","Wire cutters",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Customer and Personal Service", "Building and Construction","Transportation","Administration and Management","Design",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Active Listening", "Coordination","Critical Thinking","Monitoring","Speaking",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Manual Dexterity", "Trunk Strength","Multilimb Coordination","Static Strength","Arm-Hand Steadiness",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "47-4031.00"
        ]
    ],
    "Surveying Technician" => [
        "Tasks" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Tools_used" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2", "Entry3",
        ],
        "Knowledge" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Skills" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "Abilities" => [
            "Entry1", "Entry2",
        ],
        "datacode" => [
          "17-3031.01"
        ]
    ],
    
];




$profcode ='53-7064.00';

function find($profcode, $indus) {
    foreach($indus as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($profcode, $value['datacode'])) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

foreach($indus as $key => $values) {
    $cat = find($profcode, $values);
    if ($cat) {
       echo $cat;

       echo '<br>skills:<br>';
       foreach ($values as $value => $jobData1)
    {
   echo implode($jobData1['Skills']);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Array` is what you get, when you try to output an _array_ with `echo`. And since `$values[$key]['Skills']` itself is an array, that is not surprising here. You either need to add another level of looping over _that_ array here, or pick specific elements you want out of it some other way.

Comment: I was hoping that using array_keys() might help me pick the specific element.

Comment: That would give you an array containing the keys - which you then still would have to loop over. So why don’t you loop over `Skills` directly then?

Comment: I think I am getting somewhere with this:

foreach ($values as $value => $jobData1)
    {
   print_r($jobData1['Skills']);
   
    }

Comment: After `echo '<br>skills:<br>';`,  remove the foreach and `echo implode($values[$cat]['Skills']);` instead,  since you already have the category, you just need to access it and. it's assocated skills array

Comment: Is it via a pointer?

Comment: Not too sure what you mean, but `$cat` will give you  `"Picking and Packing"` after running your find function, once you have this, you already have access to the `"agriculture"` array as this is your currently iterated element from your outer loop (`$values`),  so on this array, you can access the array associated with `"Picking and Packing"`, and then grab it's `"Skills"` array

Comment: It should be easy but I am missing something. I have tried many different combinations for example: `echo [$values][$cat]['Skills'];`

Comment: I didn't think of doing $values[$cat] . Is that what you were hinting?

Comment: @caston yes, that's what I meant when I said you can use `echo implode($values[$cat]['Skills']);` to get the skills, using `$values[$cat]` will give you the entire array for that category (which includes the skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is primarly to do with:

```
foreach ($values as $value => $jobData1) {
  echo implode($jobData1['Skills']);
}
```

In the code above this, you first find the `$cat` key that contains your profcode through the use of your `find()` function, however, you never actually use this value when looking for the skills in the above for loop. As a result, each iteration of this loop will print out the skills for the current industry for all jobs/categories.

---

To fix the issue pointed out above, you can completely remove this foreach loop. You don't need to use a second nested loop inside of your if-statement as this loop is already done for you within your `find()` function. Here is the current flow of your code:

- Your outer for loop will loop over the industries, and will give you the name of that industry in `$key` (so "construction", "agriculture", etc.), and the data associated with that industry (the array of categories/jobs) in `$values`.
- The `find()` function then goes through the categories/jobs (eg: "Picking and Packing", "Farm Worker", etc.) in `$values`. For each iteration, the key name is stored in `$key`. Your foreach loop also grabs the associated job data array for each of these keys, and stores this data in `$value` for the current iteration. *The **main thing** here is that `$key` is a key from the `$values` array, which you have access to outside of your find() function, as `$values` is something you passed into it from your `foreach` loop.*
- You then check to see if the associated array (ie: `$value`) holds the data you're after at the `datacode` key. If it does, you return `$key`, otherwise, you return false

As a result of the above execution process, `$cat` will be set equal to the `$key` you return from your `find()` function, and so `$cat` is a key from your `$values` associative array (if $cat isn't false). This means you can grab the array associated with the key held in `$cat`, and then grab the skills array with that also (see code comments for details):

```php
foreach($indus as $key => $values) { // loop over the industries 
  $cat = find($profcode, $values); // returns a key from $values, or false
  if ($cat) { // if $cat holds a key from $values
    $skills = $values[$cat]['Skills']; // grab the category/jobs from $values using the key stored in $cat, then grab the associated 'Skills' array
    echo "$cat<br />Skills:<br />";
    echo implode(', ', $skills); // print the skills by joining the array elements with a comma
  }
}
```

this will output:

```
Picking and Packing
Skills:
Entry1, Monitoring
```

<sup>[live example](https://3v4l.org/Hr92O)</sup>

This eliminates the need for another `foreach` loop, as you've already done the traversal you need to within your `find()` function call. If each profcode is unique across different industries, then you can consider using a `break` to stop the above foreach loop early once you find your match, or use a function and `return` within the loop once a match is found.

Comment: Hi again Nick. I wondered if the third foreach was needed.

Comment: @caston yeah, since your `find()` function is giving you the key for the data you want to grab the skills from, you don't need another foreach, and can instead grab the data directly using the `$cat` ;)

Comment: I have modified the code to build a list. https://replit.com/@j354374/arraytest2

Comment: I will look into putting the code into a function that I can supply the other attributes to e.g. "abilities", "knowledge", "tools".

Comment: @caston nice, looks good. You might want to change your implode to be `implode('</li><li>', $skills) . '</li>';` as you're never closing your intermediate `<li>` tags. Also, don't forget to close the `</ul>` :P. Kevin's answer is fine if you want to practice foreach loops, just be aware that that it is less efficient as it involves looping over the array again when there is no need to do

Comment: You're right. I didn't pick it up at first. I will take a look.

Comment: If you look at this version instead of using 'skills' I have $attrib so if I change the value to 'tasks' it renders that instead. https://replit.com/@j354374/arraytest3

Comment: @caston nice, that looks good to me. I would move the `echo "</ul>";` right below the `echo implode('</li><li>', $list) . '</li>';` though. Having it outside the if-statement will means that you will always create a `</ul>`, even if you didn't open one `<ul>`. if it's inside the if-statement, it will be with the code that opens the `<ul>`

Comment: Now I have put all the attributes into an array called @attriblist and put all the code in a foreach. I know I should have used a function but I had some trouble getting it to work. 
Here it is so far: https://replit.com/@j354374/arraytest4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231539/discussion-between-nick-parsons-and-caston).

Answer (score 1):

I picked from your code and ended up with this...The find function is fine as is...just replace this section

```
foreach($indus as $key => $values) {
    $cat = find($profcode, $values);
    if ($cat) {
       echo $cat;
       echo '<br>skills:<br>';
    
      foreach($values[$cat] as $catkey => $catval) { //Break the category array further into key and values
                             if($catkey == "Skills") {   //Get the key that is labelled skills for abilities you'll change to abilities
                                  echo implode($catval); //combine the values of the skills array as desired
                                                     }
                                                   }
   
              }
}
```

Comment: This is great. I fell asleep last night but I am glad you found a solution. This gives me something to continue working on and will certainly help others too. Much appreciated.